# Как лучше написать меню навигации с паб-меню?

Tags: javascript, html

Такой вопрос, припустим есть в шапке навигация у меня
И если итмеми будуть делать переход на другую часть сайта, или прокрутку к разделу, тогда надо еще в li ставить тег a (сылку). Но если каждый итем у меня вызивает паб меню, тогда не надо в нутри тегу li вставлять сылку? а просто вешать клык на тег li?

```
 <nav class="header__menu  col-xl-5  col-md-7 ">
                  <ul class="header__list d-flex justify-content-end">
                     <li class="header__list-item">WORK</li>
                     <li class="header__list-item">ABOUT ME</li>
                     <li class="header__list-item">BLOG</li>
                     <li class="header__list-item--contact">HIRE ME</li>
                  </ul>

               </nav>
```

Comment: "Но если каждый итем у меня вызивает паб меню, тогда не надо в нутри тегу li вставлять сылку? а просто вешать клык на тег li?" -вот это вообще не понял
А в общем вставляйте ссылки и не грейте голову)

Comment: @mego4iter припустим у меня при клике на about me  , будет открыватся див, тогда мне не надо ничео меняьт в коде? или ABOUT ME обернуть  в тег (а) надо?

Comment: Лучше все итэмы меню сделать одинаковыми. Тэгам a (ссылкам), которые не вызывают переход по урлу, проставить href="#";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вероятно, вам подойдет скрипт по удалению url. Скрипт сравнивает url из window.location и из тега a. Если есть совпадение - превращает ссылку в якорь.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    deleteUrlOfLinksInThisPage();
});

function deleteUrlOfLinksInThisPage() {
    const navbar = document.querySelector('.navbar');
    const a = navbar.querySelectorAll('a');
    a.forEach(item => {
        const locate = window.location.href;
        if (item.href == locate) {
            item.href = "#";
        }
    });
}
```

Подойдет только для абсолютных ссылок